# What's the best way to compare a list<int> with the database table id column

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a `List<int>` collection which contains ids, I want to query out all the records in one database table which id in the collection.

I know I can write a method to traverse the collection and write linq to entities like `from t in context.table where t.id=id select t`, but it means I must hit database as many times as how many ids in the collection, it obviously isn't what I want.

Anyone can help?
Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (assume that *ids* is an list of IDs):

```
from t in context.table
where ids.Contains(t.Id)
select t;
```

Comment: Can this work with Join too? In my I'm trying the same thing, but i've joins in tables, and its giving me this error : 

Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.